# PHP AD LDAP Get All User Attributes and their Values, JSON Encoding Problem

Tags: php, json, search, active-directory, ldap

I'm currently trying to write a PHP script to get all attributes and their values of an AD user.

First of all, I am very grateful for every single answer and for further information about how certain things work.

The obtaining of individual properties and their values works fine. 
I think the problem arises from the fact that LDAPv3 / AD sends all responses in UTF-8 encoded form. 
Many attributes such as userCertificate, thumbnailPhoto, logonHours, and so on are of the datatype/LDAP syntax octet string or others, which consists of a byte array/binary data.

If you now query several attributes (e. g. $filter = array("*") and get the normal return array of data from LDAP, it happens that the values of the octet strings encoded in UTF-8 contain foreign characters like question marks, control characters, quotes, and other escape sequences
`\*�'=>}"` and therefore the further processing of the data structure in e.g. JSON is most of the time no longer possible.

Here is a small, edited code snippet from the script

```
        //Standard LDAP connection establishment etc. without conditions or checking anything
        $con = ldap_connect("ldap01.example.domain.com", 389);
        ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        ldap_bind($con, $user, $pwd);

        //LDAP Search
        $filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(uid=testuser123))";
        $attributes = array("*");
        $res_s = ldap_search($con, $dn, $filter, $attributes);
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($con, $res_s);
        $json = json_encode($entries);
        var_dump($json);
```

If I set the filter of the attribute to only output cn, sn and dn, the output doesn't include any foreign signs and the $entries array can be converted to JSON.

```
$attributes = array("cn", "sn", "dn");

{
    "count": 1,
    "0": {
        "cn": {
            "count": 1,
            "0": "Testuser User"
        },
        "0": "cn",
        "sn": {
            "count": 1,
            "0": "Testuser"
        },
        "1": "sn",
        "count": 2,
        "dn": "CN=Re,OU=Edited,OU=Test,DC=Example,DC=Domain,DC=com"
    }
}
```

If I instead set the filter of the attributes to array("*") to get me all attributes and their values, I won't be able to convert the $entries return array to JSON because the symbols sometimes lead to an unconvertible data structure.

```
$attributes = array("*");
...
$json = json_encode($entries);
var_dump($json); //Output: bool(false)

var_dump($entries); //Outputs:

array(2) { 
    ["count"] => int(1) 
    [0] => array(6) { 
        ["sn"] => array(2) { 
            ["count"] => int(1) 
            [0] => string(8) "Testuser" 
        }
        ["usercertificate"] => array(2) {
            ["count"] => int(1) 
            [0] => string(18xx) "�" �}\{�(�"ŉ\�ÜR"�㙽㙽0'P�7/�L��P�5\^^34{3�'< "�^㙽" 
        } 
        [1]=> string(15) "usercertificate" 
        ["count"]=> int(2) 
        ["dn"]=> string(77) "CN=Re,OU=Edited,OU=Test,DC=Example,DC=Domain,DC=com" 
    } 
}
```

What are the possibilities to avoid the described problem?
Is there a possibility to filter the attributes by the syntax entry (i.e. whether the value is an octet string, Unicode string, integer, etc.)?

Thanks in advance for any help!